# non fast-forward update in Git

Tags: git

I looked at [Note about fast-forwards](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) and know how a `fast-forward` updates a branch. But I want to know how `non fast-forward` updates a branch? Above doc says:

> For example, suppose you and somebody else started at the same commit
>   X, and you built a history leading to commit B while the other person
>   built a history leading to commit A. The history looks like this:

```
      B
     /
 ---X---A
```

> If you did ***non fast-forward*** update, the changes introduced by commit A will be lost,
>   because everybody will now start building on top of B.

But `losing changes introduced by A` is not clear for me. Does a `non fast-forward` update `overwrite` destination branch completely and remove `A` from history? So history will looks like `X -- B`. Or it simply tries to do a merge? Or another changes will occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take into account that the linked page is talking about `git push`, that is you are uploading your local branch into a remote server.

In this context, doing a fast-forward update is the usual thing: you just add commits to the tip of the remote branch. And oppositely, a non fast-forward update is a push that removes commits from the tip of the remote branch, before possibly adding more commits.

So answering your questions:

> Does a non fast-forward update overwrite destination branch completely and remove A from history?

Yes, it will do exactly that. You force the remote branch to look exactly like your local one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, B would effectively replace A in the update if you did that push. Usually you'd try to rebase B on top of A before pushing.